# How to import my module into Python in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, python-import

I would like to import a Python module (containing a Class that I've defined) into my Python Code in Visual Studio 2015 (Community).

In my main Python file, I have:

```
from RD_Modules import Subtitles
```

In a sub-directory called "RD_Modules" I created two files:

1. An `__init__.py` file containing:

from Subtitles import Subtitles

and

2. Subtitles.py containing:

class Subtitles:

```
def __init__(self):     # Intializer
```

In Visual Studio 2015, when I run the main program, I get an error saying:
"No module named subtitles"
and a line points to the from statement in the `__init__.py` file.

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.
Rajnesh